# How to make relative paths in property fields resolve correctly in persistence.xml?

Tags: jpa

We have a JSF web application and are using JPA to manage some persistent state. While still developing, we'd like to have the database tables recreated from scratch and filled with test data every time the application server launches.

To do this, we have this in our persistence.xml:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata-then-script"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="file:META-INF/data_insert.sql"/>
```

This yields and exception, "An IO error occurred with the source ddl generation script [...] (The system cannot find the file specified)".

Using an absolute path, however, works:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="file:D:\Projects\Programming\Java\wapp_project\WanderWIKI\web\META-INF\data_insert.sql"/>
```

What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Nothing missing you have an extra :) remove the *file:* in the relative path configuration, so:</s>

`<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="META-INF/data_insert.sql"/`>

the location set in the value is relative to the root of the persistence unit:

The following doc can serve you as a reference configuration https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro005.htm

UPDATE with respect to the comment

In fact, you'll have to provide an absolute path, Check the [JAVA API specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1424266923_ac0d2c5e263afad3cd084240cbbdd56a) section 8.2.1.9 properties, when referring to

- *javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source*
- *javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source*
- *javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source*

the docs say:

> When scripts are provided externally (**or when schema generation is to
>   occur into script files, as described below**), strings corresponding to
>   file URLs must be specified. In Java EE environments, **such file URL
>   specifications must be absolute paths (not relative)**. In Java EE
>   environments, all source and target file locations must be accessible
>   to the application server deploying the persistence unit

and by specifying the property `<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata-then-script"/>` your saying that the schema generation will occur first based on the meta data than based on the script, so you'll have to reference it absolutely

Comment: Doing that yields `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: META-INF/data_insert.sql`.

Comment: sorry, I didn't pay enough attention to the quesiton, I have updated my answer, you'll have to reference the script absolutely